# Active Scaffold How to list how many records are dynamically displayed per page in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, list, pagination, records, activescaffold

I found the configuration "list.per_page" of active scaffold, but i can that user enter how many records he wants to list.

I want something dynamic, because "list.per_page" is a amount static.

somebody how to know to do it?

Answer (score 0):

any active scaffold configuration that you need dinamically set, you can use a before_filter (or before_action in rails 4):

```
DEFAULT_LENGTH = 30
before_filter :set_list_length

def set_list_length
  length = @current_user.settings.per_page || DEFAULT_LENGTH
  active_scaffold_config.list.per_page 
  # you can set here almost anything you want from AS config using active_scaffold_config and @current_user
end
```